# How can you train for blind hooks with Pudge

Tags: dota-2

I have witnessed a few games where a Pudge would manage to hit a non negligible numbers of blind hooks. At first I thought it was a bit of luck but then I noticed some players are quite good at blind hooking. A few players seem to be able to guess that a player will hide behind a tower waiting for reinforcements for example.

Are there spots to hide/hook or things to do to consistently hit with blind hooks ?

Comment: In my opinion it comes from experience. The same like an Anti-Mage on Dire side which will blink from Dire Ancients to the upper right neutral camp in the jungle. That way we were able to set up a gank. Though I am pretty bad with pudge one should have some common sense about how other players behave when going invisible. **TL;DR:** Just play a few bazillion games, then you will get better eventually predicting their movements.

Comment: Pudge is, for me, one of the most fun heroes to play with. I love to play with him and experiment, but I am still not good at blind hooking (except when they move in a straight line).

Comment: It's just about getting in the enemy's mindframe, and experience. Mindframe, as to what would you do if you were them. Depending on the situation (they have the upper hand, they are behind), players behave instinctively different, and you have to guess how they will play. The other one is getting a feeling on how fast a hero can run, and where they would be in the mean time (this is for blind hooks on invis heros, low HP heros and similar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I can finally let this secret go...

MOBA games like dota is almost the same thing every time. You need to know yourself before you know your opponent. Think of battling yourself what you would do if you know you were on the surrounding and running away from a pudge. Blind hooking is an art because most players have been there done that. You will notice that your games are starting to look similar regardless of the roles. The main point of blind hooking is just knowing your range  of the Q and where the opponent will be. To make a lock between point a(you) to b(opponent) you need to read him as if you are reading yourself in what you would do in this type of circumstance. So I will layout what you need to learn before you pull it off.

1. Movement speed of each champion
2. Animation time of your hook
3. Your champion movement speed
4. Knowing your opponents movements. Typically you should be able to recognize this cat and mouse game if you played long enough.

Comment: Btw. it is called hero and not champion.

Comment: Yeah I have long switch from Dota to LoL.

Answer (score 2):

Here in my personal opinion Puj's hook and Mirana's arrows both are similar, both require anticipation and judgement plus most important some common sense. 
I found it easy to hook after I had some control over Mirana's arrows, but thats a personal thing. If you straight away want to go into hooking

1. **Check it**: Always first check your hook range, by using it in base or some random hook at hero, this way you would have sense of how much distance you can cover and the animation time as said above. Also make sure of mana, many times it happens with me I hook but there is no mana left for dismember, it causes epic fails.
2. **Totally Blind**: If you are going for blind hook, hook in or near most probable regions where hero's have been spotted frequently in game or where you think the can be. eg naix or some other farmer at nc's.
3. **Escaping Hero**: For escaping hero notice the trajectory before he disappears, keep in min his movement speed and yours, whether he can blink or not plus the distance your hook can travel.

Sometimes people try to hook only when they can  rot and get a kill, but you should also hook whenever you can especially if you are full mana, not only you are 100% sure to get a kill. In this way you are using your mana efficiently.

Try to save people with hooks when they have plenty of mana and there is minimum risk.

I am not a expert but these are the points I think can help a new guy.

The more you hook the more you get better as simple as that. You may screw up games, people will shout at you but it's worth training to get better.

Comment: About #1, I use dota_range_display with a toggle to the different ranges at different levels of the skills.

Comment: well what I actually wanted to say in edited part was that I have seen players saving hooks, by that I mean they wait for perfect opportunity which never arises. Hence the point hook as much as you can. What is edited and interpreted is also perfectly true. I didn't made myself clear enough my fault.

Comment: stackexchange websites are collaborative, feel free to re-edit if you feel like you need to add something. Thanks for your reply it is very useful.

Comment: Take care when you are coming diagonally towards a hero, sometimes people try to hook a low hp hero and when they can simply rot to get a kill. This sometimes results in epic failures you miss the hook, hero escapes and on occasions you get killed.

Answer (score 1):

Learn from this if you want. It's one one of the best pudge's videos I've seen so far

Comment: His hooks are great but he plays in normal/high bracket. If you reach very high most of his hooks will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I really prefer for blink hook only when it reach max level.

As for how to hook blindly, you'll just have to practice.